# Avoid "must contain period" restriction in dotnetopenauth urls

Tags: c#, .net, openid, dotnetopenauth

Background (which may be already evident from the multitude of questions I've asked about DNOA thus far): I'm working on a web application portal running in my employer's intranet. However, since this is an intranet, all of the various relying parties (and the provider) have urls that look like this: `http://servername/path`; notably missing a TLD.

This code in DotNetOpenAuth (`UntrustedWebRequestHandler.IsUriAllowable(Uri uri)`) performs the following check:

```
if (!uri.Host.Contains(".")) {
    return failsUnlessWhitelisted("it does not contain a period in the host name.");
}
```

Obviously since all of my RP's are simply server names with no TLDs they all fail this check. 
Now, I realize I could just add them all to the web.config whitelist (which I've tried for a few and it works as expected), but seeing as new servers will be added dynamically I don't see this as an ideal solution.

So my question is: Should I be trying to modify web.config dynamically? (preliminary research I've done on this indicates it would be a pain)
Or, is there some way to programatically set the whitelist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no programmatic way to modify the host whitelist, unfortunately.

If you are in a trusted environment, you can circumvent the `UntrustedWebRequestHandler` class and use a web request handler which doesn't include the host name check (or checks that it matches whatever policy you need). There is a built-in `DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler` that you can use that is a straight pass-through (doesn't add any extra network-level security checks) that is recommended if you trust all the servers you will ask DotNetOpenAuth to connect to.

```
var rp = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
rp.Channel.WebRequestHandler = new StandardWebRequestHandler();

var op = new OpenIdProvider();
op.Channel.WebRequestHandler = new StandardWebRequestHandler();
```

If you want to apply some more cautious policy (perhaps have some centralized list of whitelisted hosts), you can implement the `IDirectWebRequestHandler` yourself, and you can use [the existing `UntrustedWebRequestHandler` class for inspiration if necessary](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/blob/master/src/DotNetOpenAuth.Core/Messaging/UntrustedWebRequestHandler.cs). Then of course set the above properties to your own implementation.